# SQL Query where a foreign key of a foreign key is used

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-server-2012

I need to make a query as follows:

Something like this (not real SQL but this is what I'd like to do):

```
SELECT * FROM price_entry WHERE sum = 100 AND fk_service_order.fk_service='REPAIR'
```

So I'd like to get all `price_entry` rows where `sum` column has value 100 and `fk_service_order` would point to a `service_order` row that has 'REPAIR' value on it's `fk_service` column

EDIT: And yes `sum` is actually name of a column here.

Comment: Would you please share table structures ?

Comment: Please show us some data, or table structure, or both.  If you intend `sum` to be an actual sum of a column, then you'd have to also use `GROUP BY` or an analytic function.

Comment: Sum is in this case a column. Bad naming I know. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming such a setup:

**price_entry**

- Id
- sum
- fk_service

**service_order**

- Id
- fk_service_order

  ```
  SELECT * 
  FROM   price_entry 
  WHERE  sum = 100 
         AND EXISTS 
         (
             SELECT TOP 1 1 
             FROM   service_order so 
             WHERE  fk_service= so.Id AND fk_service_order = 'REPAIR'
         )
  ```